# Git multi cherry pick with Bash throwing error

Tags: java, bash, git

I am trying to implement Git cherry pick for multiple commit Ids at once. 
But it fails, or either this is not how it should be used.

I am trying to use bash command from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553705/9614476

```
  #!/bin/bash

  if [ -z $1 ]; then
      echo "Equivalent to running git-cherry-pick on each of the commits in the range specified.";
      echo "";
      echo "Usage:  $0 start^..end";
      echo "";
      exit 1;
  fi

  git rev-list --reverse --topo-order $1 | while read rev
  do
    git cherry-pick $rev || break
  done
```

I created a target for ant like this :

```
<target name="git_multi_cherry_pick">
    <echo message="START: MultiMerge"/>
    <exec executable="C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" osfamily="windows" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${gitMultiCherryPick}"/>
        <arg value="${gitCommitIds}"/>
    </exec>
    <exec executable="/bin/bash" osfamily="unix" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${gitMultiCherryPick}"/>
        <arg value="${gitCommitIds}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

And I am using `AntExecutor` from Java to call the above target.
`AntExecutor code can be found here -  https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-ant/blob/master/src/test/java/org/asciidoctor/ant/AntExecutor.java`

```
        Map<String, String> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
        propertiesMap.put("gitMultiCherryPick", "git-multi-cherry-pick.sh");
        propertiesMap.put("gitCommitIds", "204a3e81712000d09a2794cc4ef1d090c4280f4e,9c5242d6a15b14032e9fc1f408be3c91026b1e1f");
        List<String> sf_build = AntExecutor.executeAntTask("FullPath \\resources\\build\\build.xml",
                "git_multi_cherry_pick", propertiesMap);
```

But it fails with this error :

`The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command., 204a3e81712000d09a2794cc4ef1d090c4280f4e,9c5242d6a15b14032e9fc1f408be3c91026b1e1f, git-multi-cherry-pick.sh, fatal: ambiguous argument '204a3e81712000d09a2794cc4ef1d090c4280f4e,9c5242d6a15b14032e9fc1f408be3c91026b1e1f':`

I think that is not how we pass the commitIds. Has anyone used the above bash script before?

Comment: IIRC `git cherry-pick` can already handle several commits at once. Having said that, it sounds like you are actually looking for `git rebase`, no?

Comment: So my requirement is something like this , Take multiple commit Ids as input and create a branch out of it, the first commit ID being the base, and the next commit ids to be merged into that base.

Comment: It still sounds suspiciously like rebasing: `git checkout -b your_branch end_commit; git rebase --onto target_commit starting_commit your_branch;` (comparable to `git checkout -b your_branch target_commit; git cherry_pick starting_commit..end_commit;`

Comment: So here is the catch, the `target_commit starting_commit` can be in mixed way. i.e. it may not be consecutive commit ids, it can be like if there are commit ids like 1,2,3,4,5 then I would like to only commit  2 and 4. So I would have to commit in loop, right?

Comment: Yes, but your script performs a `rev-list`, so you would get all commits between those two commits already. Without a range, you would apply all commits

Comment: Ok, I see that now. So is there a way to do that using `bash` or do I need to write it fully custom?

Comment: @NagendraSingh, you are being suggested to use `git rebase`. 
 Please, read the man page of `git rebase`.  What you try to do is a rebase of your branch (complete) to another place.  Look at the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are actually looking for `git rebase`, not `git cherry-pick` (both of which can perform the same work). `git cherry-pick` in recent Git release can even process multiple commits directly, without the need for an external loop.

<s>To address your specific question: when specifying several commit refs on the command line, those need to be separated by your shells IFS (input field separator), which is usually whitespace and rarely a comma (`,`).</s>

Possible solutions:

- Change your map value to `204a3e81712000d09a2794cc4ef1d090c4280f4e 9c5242d6a15b14032e9fc1f408be3c91026b1e1f` (pay attention to quoting in your script)
- Set `IFS` in your script to `','`

---

`git cherry-pick` can already pick multiple commits at once (see [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt-ltcommitgt82308203)). You still need to fix the value in your map from comma to blank, but then you could simplify your shell script.

This also fixes the problem of using `rev-list` without a range, but only 2 starting points (`abc123 def456` instead of `abc123..def456`). It would traverse all of your history, not only commits between your two refs. Drop the `rev-list` and utilize `cherry-pick` directly:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Equivalent to running git-cherry-pick on each of the commits in the range specified.";
    echo "";
    echo "Usage: $0 start^..end";
    echo "";
    exit 1;
fi


# do not quote parameter, we need potential whitespace preserved
git cherry-pick $1
```

(and you do not need `bash`, `sh` will totally suffice for a script like this)

Comment: After giving space now it gives `The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command., fatal: bad object 204a3e81712000d09a2794cc4ef1d090c4280f4e, exec returned: 128]` bad object error.

Comment: I ran this command `git show 204a3e81712000d09a2794cc4ef1d090c4280f4e` and its running fine, but still bad object error is pretty weird.

Comment: @NagendraSingh the error message still contains the `,` comma character that should be removed.

Comment: I changed my map to `propertiesMap.put("gitCommitIds", "204a3e81712000d09a2794cc4ef1d090c4280f4e f48b8cfeb852495489b6198d6c73eef3f5f53d9e");`

Comment: Are you sure? The error message contains »`fatal: bad object …80f4e,`. But I'm not sure if Ant is being funny here. I'm not sure how it is passing its parameters. Maybe it is already escaping or quoting its arguments. Do you expect N commits or only 2 at most? if only 2, I suggest defining separate arguments for them and putting them into a single value

Comment: Yes, I can paste the ant logs here : 

`The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command., Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe' with arguments:
'git-multi-cherry-pick.sh'
'204a3e81712000d09a2794cc4ef1d090c4280f4e f48b8cfeb852495489b6198d6c73eef3f5f53d9e'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command., Start Cherry Pick, fatal: bad object 204a3e81712000d09a2794cc4ef1d090c4280f4e, exec returned: 128]`

Comment: @NagendraSingh Can you try with a single commit only? Can you check if the working directory is set correctly when executing the git command (add `pwd` and `git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir`)? What happens if you run `git show` from within your script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211017/discussion-between-nagendra-singh-and-knittl).

Comment: As per your suggestion I changed the `cherry-pick` to `rebase`, but how do I validate this: 

`#!/bin/bash

echo 'Start Cherry Pick'

cd $4 || exit

echo 'Switched to '$4
git clone repoURL.git .
git checkout -f origin/master
git checkout -b TestCEAS 212e4a80dd8638af35aeaf36776bffc4cda85df5
git rebase --onto 212e4a80dd8638af35aeaf36776bffc4cda85df5 a0b21246fec005f89fbf8fa5051098981bc4e69a TestCEAS`

Comment: But how do I verify if the new branch `TestCEAS` has only commits range given in `212e4a80dd8638af35aeaf36776bffc4cda85df5 a0b21246fec005f89fbf8fa5051098981bc4e69a`

Comment: Also when you wrote this `git checkout -b your_branch end_commit; git rebase --onto target_commit starting_commit your_branch;`, end_commit means -> last commit id and starting_commit means -> First Commit Id, but what is 'target_commit', is this the last commit id too?

Comment: So my doubt is why not just do `git checkout -b your_branch end_commit;` as it will extract all the commit till that commit id. Why is this required `git rebase --onto target_commit starting_commit your_branch;` and if its required then what is difference between `end_commit` and `target_commit`.

Comment: I thought we already agreed that `rebase` will not work, because you are trying to pick individual commits that are not all directly linked (IOW your commit graph contains "gaps"). Test your script without Ant first to pinpoint your actual problem. If the script works, see if Ant is starting it incorrectly

Comment: I changed my approach now,  so user can only select start commit and end commit ids from a branch, and then proceed further.

Comment: I see. A totally different question then. But nevermind. `your_branch` is the name of the branch which should eventually contain all your commits. `target_commit` is where your changes should be applied to. `start_commit` is the commit from where to start. It is _excluded_ from your result (use `start_commit^` to include it). `end_commit` is the last commit that should be in your resulting history